# AS3 Typed Objects Serialization to C# Hashtables and back

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, serialization

i need to serialize AS3 strong typed Objects, send them to a C# Application and then be able to derserialize them as Hashtables/Dictionarys or so because i have no corresponding C# Class. I then will make some changes to that Hastable and need to be able to send them back to the as3 App.

I tried using JSON (see this question with bounty [Typed AS3 JSON Encoder and Decoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764646/typed-as3-json-encoder-and-decoder)) as i already got JSON serialization to Hashtables in C#. It does not work because AS3 has no support for typed JSON.

I also looked in XML and found asx3m http://code.google.com/p/asx3m/ which is strong typed in as3 but i can find a solution to serialie and deserialize this to proper hashtables in c#.

Comment: I have now forked the json part of http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/ and added typed object support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can read untyped JSON in C# and send it back to ActionScript. The only problem is strong type support. Why not use untyped JSON deserialization on AS side and then convert typeless objects to typed ones?
To do that, you need:

- Pass type info somehow, for example, in special property: { __type: "flash.geom.Rectangle" }
- Deserialize untyped object
- Get type with getDefinitionByName and create typed object (constructor should not require arguments)
- Iterate through untyped objects properties with for..in and set corresponding ones in typed object.

Comment: i was looking for a library. If i build your stuff i can also directly build a strong typed json encoder and decoder myself. Seems like i have too...