# Serializing and Deserializing object with JSON

Tags: python, json, serialization, actionscript, deserialization

Is there a way or a library made to deserialize a JSON string into a typed object in ActionScript and Python?

For eg.

```
class Person
{

    String name;

    int age;

}

Person person = new Person("John", "22");

String jsonString = JSON.Serialize(person);

Person person2 = (Person) JSON.Deserialize(jsonString);
```

So, the last statement basically casts the object we get after deserializing the jsonString into the Person object.

Answer (score 3):

I can only speak for Python. There is a built in library for JSON access, it can be viewed in the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

Unfortunately, out of the box, you cannot serialize/deserialize objects, just `dict`s, `list`s and simply types. You have to write specific object encoders to do so. This is pretty much covered in the docs.

Comment: Between us we have a complete answer!

Answer (score 2):

For AS3 you can use as3corelib by Mike Chambers.

https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/tree/master/src/com/adobe/serialization/json

**Edit**: After some Googling I ended up back on SO at this question: [Typed AS3 JSON Encoder and Decoder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764646/typed-as3-json-encoder-and-decoder)  It seems that there is a library for doing typed deserialization, but it is not totally robust and fails on some data types.  If you think you can handle the restrictions then it might be the best option short of writing your own parser or gettting into something heavy like BlazeDS.

http://code.google.com/p/ason/

Comment: the library you mentioned is more like converting a typed object into json and then from json we just get name-value mappings which are to be parsed and formulated into a typed object. Is there something out of the box that I can use for getting a typed object out of the json box (the library).

Comment: @Saurabh - found one, but it might not be robust enough for you. I've no personal experience of it.

Comment: My AS3 JSON class supports types, preserves references to allow cycles, custom type mappings (e.g. "Dic"="flash.utils.Dictionary"), custom type packers (a.k.a. custom converters/serializers), and includes built-in type packers for ByteArray, Dictionary, Date, custom high-precision DateTime/Int64/UInt64 types, GUIDs, arbitrary Vector.<T> types, and more. It also pre-filters runtime type names before mapping so your mappings and packers can deal with code-friendly names like `Vector.<T>` instead of `__AS3__.vec::Vector.<T>`, and `flash.utils.Dictionary` instead of `flash.utils::Dictionary`.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with this:

```
import json

class Serializer:

    @staticmethod
    def encode_obj(obj):
        if type(obj).__name__ =='instance':
            return obj.__dict__ 
    @staticmethod
    def serialize(obj):
        return json.dumps(obj, default=Serializer.encode_obj)

class TestClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

t = TestClass()   
json_str = Serializer.serialize(t)
```

Comment: Note that an even more generic solution would use `if hasattr(obj, '__dict__'): return obj.__dict__` in the `Serializer.encode_obj` body - then any object's internal attribute dictionary (state) will simply be serialized. Which in turn can be used to simplify this even more: `json.dumps(t, default=lambda o: o.__dict__)`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No there is not. JSON doesn't include typed objects except for a few such as Arrays. The as3Corelib does recognize these. But as you mentioned, you get back an Object with name value pairs. Since JSON does not contain your custom actionscript classes, there is no automatic way to convert a JSON object into a typed actionscript object.

The as3corelib is a great utility for JSON in flash. However the latest build of the flash player (version 10.3) includes JSON as a native data type.

But it is not very difficult to create a class with a constructor that takes the JSON object as an argument, and you can parse it into the class variables. I have to do this all the time when working with the facebook Graph API.